# how to convert a for loop calculation to a mathematical formula?

Tags: java, math, for-loop

Sorry, I am not good at math
But is there a mathematical formula that could replace the below code, i.e. to calculate the points given qid,points, and factor without a loop?

```
    for (int i = 1; i < qid; i++) 
    {
       points = points * factor;
    }
```

How can I convert the above code into a mathematical formula than can be calculated in a single line without a loop
thanks.

Comment: ur calculating points value will be the same for infinite no. of loops.. R u lookng for the same..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming `points` is initialized to `1`, it is equvalent to `points = factor^(qid-1)`, or for general case: `points_after = points_before * factor^(qid-1)`

The loop repeats `qid - 1` times [`i` get the values: `1,2,...,qid-1`, for value `i==qid` you do not multiple], and in each iteration you multiple `points` by `factor` each time, so you multiple it by total of `factor^(qid-1)`

Comment: how do you figure this out? do you use a pen and paper to trace the loop with test values and try to test several equations or something ?

Comment: @Tamer: No need to, the loop repeats `qid-1` times because it is from 1 to `qid` [not includin `qid`], and increases by 1 every iteration, thus you get `points = points * factor * factor * ... * factor` [`qid-1` times], which is by definition `points * factor^(qid-1)`

Comment: I wanted to understand how to do it on my own, I meant to ask something like what courses should I study to be able to do that :)

Comment: You should look at courses that include mathematical induction and proofs.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially your code is representing "points = points * factor<sup>qid - 1</sup>". How you represent that in code depends on the language/platform. For example, you might use Java code like this:

```
points *= Math.pow(factor, qid - 1);
```

The right answer will *also* depend on the types of `points` and `factor`, neither of which you've told us...

(It's also possible that you meant to start your loop at 0 instead of 1, in which case remove the `- 1` from the above code, too...)

Answer (score 0):

Exponents.

```
points *= power( factor, qid - 1 )
```

Should work.

Comment: The loop repeats `qid-1` times.

Comment: You're right.. So if qid is 5, the loop will run 4 times, and if factor is .5, it will result in .5*.5*.5*.5, but if just QID was the exponent, it would be 5 times. Edited, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

points *= Math.pow(factor, qid);

Comment: The loop repeats `qid-1` times.